# Error code from UIActivityViewController's completionWithItemsHandler

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, photosframework

The completion handler of UIActivityViewController is:

```
typedef void (^UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)(UIActivityType __nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray * __nullable returnedItems, NSError * __nullable activityError);
```

And from the `activityError` I can check if code is one of:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAccessUserDeniedError,
ALAssetsLibraryWriteDiskSpaceError, etc
```

However, The errors are deprecated since `Asset Library` is deprecated, but `UIActivityViewController` isn't deprecated yet, what are the equivalent of those errors in Photos framework?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you would use `ALAssetsLibraryXXXError` codes with `UIActivityViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy Assets Library was the standard before, so I assumed the activity VC would use it internally, but now what should be the error code when Assets Library's deprecated?

Comment: What do you mean it was the standard before? It was never appropriate to use the asset library error codes for `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy OK, ignore what I said, what should be the error code now?

Comment: It's not documented anywhere.

Comment: @rmaddy I vaguely remembered that I tried to reproduce the error scenario and checked the error code, that's how I got the impression it was using the ones from assets library, I think I'll do again just to see what code it is. Thanks!